# Potentially identity elements in an Abelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

I didn't see this problem before. I motivated by the questions

1. [Is every commutative group structure underlying at least one (unitary, commutative) ring structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154964/is-every-commutative-group-structure-underlying-at-least-one-unitary-commutati/154979#154979)
2. [A basic question about rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154852/a-basic-question-about-rings/154882#154882)

Suppose A is an Abelian group such that it is possible to define an associative unitary ring structure on A. An element $x\in A$ is called potentially identity if there exists an associative ring $R$ such that $A$ is the additive group of $R$ and $x=1_R$, the identity element of $R$. Determine the set of all potentially identity elements of $A$.

Comment: Note that if a potential identity $x$ has finite order $n,$ then the group $A$ must have exponent $n.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Very good point!

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Actually, that gives a complete answer when $x$ has finite order $n$. If $A$ has exponent $n$, then it's a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module, and the subgroup $\langle x\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $x$ is injective as a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module, so $A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\oplus A'$ for some subgroup $A'$, which can be made into a ring with $A'^2=0$.

Comment: If $x$ has infinite order, there are some obvious restrictions on how divisible $x$ must be. The set of integers $n$ for which $ny=x$ has a solution must be closed under multiplication.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: The solution for the finite exponent case is now completed by your comment. The most complicated case is probably torsion free case.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: Also, if $x$ is divisible by $n$, then $nA=A$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for you the notion of potentially invertible elements of a semigroup introduced by E. Shutov [E.S. Lyapin, "Semigroups" , Amer. Math. Soc.].